# google apps script is too slow when drawing multiple charts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to google apps script.
I made a web app to display a few charts based on the data from google spreadsheet.
But it takes time to have all the charts loaded when the page is shown.
Also, sometimes one or two charts are not loaded.
Is there any solution to make my program more efficient?
Thank you.

js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

//do something here to get parameters (name,sDay_load,eDay_load,)

google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getData);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getSleepData);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getHeartRateData);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getOxygenSaturationData);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getBodyTemperatureData);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getMorningData);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getMorningSymotomsData);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getNightData);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getNightSymotomsData);

function getData(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).getChartsData(name,sDay_load,eDay_load,"weight");
};

function getSleepData(){
  // sleep
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawSleepChart).getChartsData(name,sDay_load,eDay_load,"sleep");
};
function getHeartRateData(){
  // heart rate              
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawHeartRateChart).
getChartsData(name,sDay_load,eDay_load,"heartRate");
};
function getOxygenSaturationData(){
  // oxygen saturation  
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawOxygenSaturationChart).
getChartsData(name,sDay_load,eDay_load,"oxygenSaturation");
};
function getBodyTemperatureData(){
  // body temperature
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawBodyTemperatureChart).
  getChartsData(name,sDay_load,eDay_load,"bodyTemperature");
};
function getMorningData(){
  // sleep, tiredness, appetite
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawMorningChart).
  getChartsData(name,sDay_load,eDay_load,"morning");
};
function getMorningSymotomsData(){
  // symptoms
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawMorningSymptomsChart).
  getChartsData(name,sDay_load,eDay_load,"morningSymptoms");
};
function getNightData(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawNightChart).getChartsData(name,sDay_load,eDay_load,"night");
};
function getNightSymotomsData(){
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawNightSymptomsChart).
 getChartsData(name,sDay_load,eDay_load,"nightSymptoms");
};

function drawChart(dataReturned) {
  //weight
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  //add columns here
  //set options here 

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('Weight_chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  };

  function drawSleepChart(dataReturnedSleep) {
  var data_sleep = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  //add columns
    data_sleep.addRows(dataReturnedSleep);

    var chart_sleep = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('Sleep_chart_div'));
    chart_sleep.draw(data_sleep, options);
  };

  //heart rate
  function drawHeartRateChart(dataReturnedHeartRate) {
  var data_heartRate = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    //add columns
    data_heartRate.addRows(dataReturnedHeartRate);

    //set options here 

    var chart_heartRate = new          google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('HeartRate_chart_div'));
    chart_heartRate.draw(data_heartRate, options);
  };

  //oxygen saturation
  function drawOxygenSaturationChart(dataReturnedOxygen) {
  var data_oxygenSaturation = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  //add columns
    data_oxygenSaturation.addRows(dataReturnedOxygen);

    //set options here 
    var chart_oxygenSaturation = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('OxygenSaturation_chart_div'));
    chart_oxygenSaturation.draw(data_oxygenSaturation, options);
  };

  //body temperature
  function drawBodyTemperatureChart(dataReturnedBodyTem) {
  var data_bodyTemperature = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    //add columns
    data_bodyTemperature.addRows(dataReturnedBodyTem);

    //set options here 

    var chart_bodyTemperature = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('BodyTemperature_chart_div'));
    chart_bodyTemperature.draw(data_bodyTemperature, options);
  };

  // morning
  function drawMorningChart(dataReturnedMorning){
    var data_morning = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    //add columns

    data_morning.addRows(dataReturnedMorning);

    //set options here 

    var chart_Morning = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('Morning_chart_div'));
    chart_Morning.draw(data_morning, options);
  };
  // night
  function drawNightChart(dataReturnedNight){
    var data_night = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    //add columns

    data_night.addRows(dataReturnedNight);

    //set options here 

    var chart_Night = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('Night_chart_div'));
    chart_Night.draw(data_night, options);
  }

  //try
  var name = document.getElementById("athletename").textContent;

  //scatter chart
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['scatter']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawScatterChart);

  function drawMorningSymptomsChart(dataReturned) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    //add columns
    data.addRows(dataReturned);

    //set options here 
    var container = document.getElementById('Morning_symptoms');
    var node = container.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(node);
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Scatter.convertOptions(options));        

    // var chart = new google.charts.Scatter(document.getElementById('Morning_symptoms'));

    // chart.draw(data, google.charts.Scatter.convertOptions(options));
  }

  function drawNightSymptomsChart(dataReturned) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    //add columns

    data.addRows(dataReturned);

    //set options here 

    var container = document.getElementById('Night_symptoms');
    var node = container.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(node);
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Scatter.convertOptions(options));

  });

}
```

---

gs

```
function getChartsData(targetName, startDay, endDay, flg){

    let wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let ws = wb.getSheetByName(LOGIN_USER);
    if (!ws){
      wb.insertSheet(LOGIN_USER);
      } else {
      ws.clear();
    }
    
    let lastrow_db = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(DBSHEETNAME).getLastRow();
    var req = "=QUERY(" + DBSHEETNAME + "!A1:AX" + lastrow_db
    \+ ","select \* where A \>= date '" + startDay + "' and A \<= date '" + endDay + "' and B = '" +         targetName + "'")";
    
    ws.getRange(1,1).setFormula(req);
    
    let lastrow_queryresult = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(LOGIN_USER).getLastRow();
    
    switch(flg){
      case "weight":
      //get all values and then get rid of unnecessary ones
      break;
    
      case "sleep":
      //get all values and then get rid of unnecessary ones    
      break;
    
      case "heartRate":
      //get all values and then get rid of unnecessary ones
      break;
    
      case "oxygenSaturation":
      //get all values and then get rid of unnecessary ones
      break;
    
      case "bodyTemperature":
      //get all values and then get rid of unnecessary ones
      break;
    
      case "morning":
      //get all values and then get rid of unnecessary ones
      break;
    
      case "morningSymptoms":
      //get all values and then get rid of unnecessary ones
      break;
    
      case "night":
      //get all values and then get rid of unnecessary ones
      break;
    
      case "nightSymptoms":
      //get all values and then get rid of unnecessary ones
      break;
    
      default:
    
      break;
    
    }
    
    return arr;

}
```

Comment: Your `drawChart` function contains inner functions - is that correct? - please try with only  asingle chart, then, check closely your code. I might be wrong, but, the delay could be due the filtering....can you share a sample spreadsheet with some sample data?

Comment: the delay could be due the filtering.
I think so, too.
But I have no idea how to reduce filtering.
If I could retrieve all the data and store them somewhere the loading might be faster.
But seems like there is nothing like global variable I cound use in google apps script.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eI9v95hhB4jIOuyOmexRgMfHjyf1RZhuR99Xrec0L6Y/edit#gid=0
This is the sample data.
There are about 3000 records. And it keeps growing since data is added every day.